# Missing 1 required positional argument - 'Self'?

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following method of a certain class:

```
def make_payment(self, cost):
```

and the following at the main file:

```
print(money_machine.make_payment(drink.cost))
```

why is it returning this? (I am following a code-along session and everything seems to be fine with his code)
TypeError: MoneyMachine.make_payment() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cost'

MAIN:

> ```
> from menu import Menu, MenuItem
> from coffee_maker import CoffeeMaker
> from money_machine import MoneyMachine
>
> """1print report
> 2check resources sufficies
> process coins 
> check transaction successful
> make coffee
> """
> coffee_maker = CoffeeMaker()
> menu = Menu()
> money_machine = MoneyMachine
>
> is_on = True
> while is_on:
>
>     print(menu.get_items())
>     order = input("your order: ")
>     if order == 'off':
>         is_on = False
>     elif order == "report":
>         coffee_maker.report()
>     else:
>         drink = menu.find_drink(order)
>         if coffee_maker.is_resource_sufficient(drink):
>             if money_machine.make_payment(drink.cost):
>                 coffee_maker.make_coffee(drink)
> ```

MONEY MACHINE:

```
class MoneyMachine:

    CURRENCY = "$"

    COIN_VALUES = {
        "quarters": 0.25,
        "dimes": 0.10,
        "nickles": 0.05,
        "pennies": 0.01
    }

    def __init__(self):
        self.profit = 0
        self.money_received = 0

    def report(self):
        """Prints the current profit"""
        print(f"Money: {self.CURRENCY}{self.profit}")

    def process_coins(self):
        """Returns the total calculated from coins inserted."""
        print("Please insert coins.")
        for coin in self.COIN_VALUES:
            self.money_received += int(input(f"How many {coin}?: ")) * self.COIN_VALUES[coin]
        return self.money_received

    def make_payment(self, cost):
        """Returns True when payment is accepted, or False if insufficient."""
        print(self.money_received)
        self.process_coins()
        if self.money_received >= cost:
            change = round(self.money_received - cost, 2)
            print(f"Here is {self.CURRENCY}{change} in change.")
            self.profit += cost
            self.money_received = 0
            return True
        else:
            print("Sorry that's not enough money. Money refunded.")
            self.money_received = 0
            return False
```

Comment: How do you instantiate `money_machine()`? Can we see the class? -- I'd imagine you are not instantiating the class correctly, in which case self isn't a passed attribute of the called method

Comment: money_machine = MoneyMachine

Comment: yes, your issue is the instantiation, please see my answer.

Comment: `money_machine = MoneyMachine` creates an alias you want `money_machine = MoneyMachine()` to create an instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comments, the issue is that you are not instantiating your class correctly.

Overall your instantiation code should be more like this, which is the correct way to instantiate a class:

`money_machine = MoneyMachine()`

then calling methods would insatiate it correctly and you pass `self` in, so `money_machine.make_payment(drink.cost)` would then work as expected.

Instantiating a class is essentially calling the class's `__init__()` method, this is also where you would define any required arguments if needed when creating a copy of the class. For example:

```
class MoneyMachine():
    def __init__(self, currency_type):
        # here you must instantiate with currency_type defined
        self.currency_type = currency_type
        self.profit = 0
        self.money_received = 0
```

`usa_money_machine = MoneyMachine(currency_type='USD')`

Comment: mother of god. Thank you very much!